# Improve execution time of high precision calculation in Go

Tags: go, gps, precision, raspberry-pi3

**Note!** The original question was based on me getting confused with 64-bit types on 32-bit systems. Turns out that my original code failed because I had used float32 for a value that should have been float64. The error made me think that I couldn't use float64 on a 32-bit system. Which was quickly corrected in the comments. Thanks to @BurakSerdar and @Adrian.
I have left the original question below in order to not invalidate the comments.

I have refactored my code and I have two viable alternatives. One is based on the answer posted by @PakUula, using int64 and string manipulation. The other is using float64.
The float64 solution has ~25% higher execution time, but the code seems easier to read.

Running benchmark tests on the Raspberry pi3 gave the following results for the two methods:

```
BenchmarkAll/int64Method-4            286648          3977 ns/op          32 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/float64Method-4          242878          5000 ns/op          24 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

**Float64 method**

```
func float64Method(msg []byte) string {
    payload := msg[6:]

    latFloat := float64(int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(payload[8:12])))
    precFloat := float64(int8(payload[24])) / 100

    latSum := (latFloat + precFloat) / 1e7
    return fmt.Sprintf("%2.9f", latSum)
}
```

**int64 method**

```
func int64Method(msg []byte) string {
    payload := msg[6:]

    rawLatUint32 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(payload[8:12])
    rawLatInt32 := int32(rawLatUint32)
    rawLatInt64 := int64(rawLatInt32)
    fixLat8 := int8(payload[24])
    
    highPrecLat := rawLatInt64*100 + int64(fixLat8)
    negative := (highPrecLat < 0)
    sign := ""
    if negative {
        sign = "-"
        highPrecLat = -highPrecLat
    }

    latInt := highPrecLat / precision
    latFrac := highPrecLat % precision
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d.%09d", sign, latInt, latFrac)
}
```

Working example on go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/cQo67gMDwGS

I was looking for a method to convert the 4 byte little endian values directly to int32. It doesn't appear to exist in the built-in packages.

**Original post**
I am creating a topographical surveying system using a Raspberry Pi3 (32-bit) and a Ublox M8 GPS receiver.
The code is going to be written in Go. (Go 1.19.2)

The Ublox receiver generates a High Precision GPS position in a byte message. The latitude and longitude values are each made from a 4byte signed integer (I4) and a 1byte signed integer (I1). The byte values are LittleEndian.

The high precision coordinates are put together by adding the I4 and the I1 like this:
Degrees * 1e-7 = I4 + (I1 * 1e-2)

A lat/long position will be displayed as degrees with 9 decimals, e.g: Lat: 48.944665243°, Lon: -13.117730989°

This is where I run into problems with my limited knowledge of Go (and mathematics).
None of the built in datatypes can do arithmetic with numbers of this size (my system is 32-bit), so I used math/big to get the correct result. However, math/big appears to require a lot of processing power. I had the code running on a 64-bit system where I could use built in types and string formatting to get the correct result. Using math/big caused processing time to quadruple.

I am looking for advice on how to improve this bit of code. I don't know if there is a better way to do this without using math/big. Also I really don't know if my use of math/big is correct.

```
    latFloat := big.NewFloat(float64(int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(payload[12:16]))))
    precFloat := big.NewFloat(float64(int8(payload[25])) / 100)
    latSum := big.NewFloat(0.0)
    latSum.Add(latSum, latFloat)
    latSum.Add(latSum, precFloat)
    multip := big.NewFloat(0.0000001)
    latSum.Mul(latSum, multip)
    h.Lat = fmt.Sprint(latSum.Text('f', 9))
```

There is a working example available in Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/EAN4YmqeuwO

In addition, I wonder about the binary.LittleEndian decoding. Is there a way to do this without using the Uint32 method of binary.LittleEndian. It seems unnecessary to go via Uint32 to int32 to get the correct value.

Comment: You can use floating point, but may lose some precision. Alternatively, all the operations until the last multiplication can be done using integers, without using math.Big at all.

Comment: `float64` should provide enough precision, and should be available even on 32-bit architectures (as you can see, your own code is already using `float64`). You shouldn't need `math.Big`. There's also no reason to convert `uint32` to `int32` to `float64`, you can just convert `uint32` to `float64`. Your playground code has even more unnecessary conversions like `float32(int32(c))`.

Comment: @Adrian, the byte values are signed integers. They can be positive or negative. If you convert the Uint32 directly to float64 then the negative values will not be correct. See example: [link](https://go.dev/play/p/RBUhzI8H_Zo). I was wondering if there was a way to decode the value other than the Uint32 method of binary.LittleEndian, since it requires conversion to int32. Regarding float64, you and Burak Serdar are of course correct. I have to check why my first attempt failed. I think I will delete this question.

Comment: "A lat/long position will be displayed as degrees with 9 decimals" are you sure this is sensible? Are you sure your GPS signal is accurate to 20cm?

Comment: @Volker, this will be a DGPS solution with a Base Station and a Rover. The goal is to check the achievable accuracy with different types of GPS antennas. Absolute position is not a concern, but rather relative positions with as high accuracy as possible. 9 decimals is what the Ublox M8 provides, so that is what will be recorded, even though that is a precision which is completely un-realistic.

Comment: @authoritah Legit reason!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `int64`? Go runtime supports it on 32-bit platforms quite efficiently.

**REWORKED**

Here is an example: https://go.dev/play/p/XRVKaGvNMrw

```
const precisionFactor = 1_000_000_000
// Convert fixed-precision int to a string
func IntStringWithPrecision(val int64) string {
    negative := (val < 0)
    sign := ""
    if negative {
        sign = "-"
        val = -val
    }
    deg := val / precisionFactor
    frac := val % precisionFactor
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d.%09d", sign, deg, frac)
}
// Convert a float to a string with 9 digits after dot
func FloatStringWithPrecision(val float64) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%0.9f", val)
}

// Parse payload as a fixed-precision int
func GetLatAsInt(payload []byte) int64 {
    rawLatUint32 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(payload[12:16])
    rawLatInt32 := int32(rawLatUint32)
    rawLatInt64 := int64(rawLatInt32)

    fixLat8 := int8(payload[25])

    return rawLatInt64*100 + int64(fixLat8)
}

// Parse payload as a float
func GetLatAsFloat(payload []byte) float64 {
    latFloat := float64(int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(payload[12:16])))
    precFloat := float64(int8(payload[25])) / 100

    return (latFloat + precFloat) / 1e7
}
```

The trick is that we keep the 9-digits precision inside an integer, and split is into integer and fractional part doing a `divmod` by the integer equivalent of `1e9`.

Output is:

```
test(305419896, -112)
Using integer: 30.541989488
Using float:   30.541989488
test(100, -56)
Using integer: 0.000009944
Using float:   0.000009944
test(1, 2)
Using integer: 0.000000102
Using float:   0.000000102
test(-1, 2)
Using integer: -0.000000098
Using float:   -0.000000098
test(-10, 20)
Using integer: -0.000000980
Using float:   -0.000000980
test(-305419896, 9)
Using integer: -30.541989591
Using float:   -30.541989591
```

As you can see, the results are identical

Benchmark: https://go.dev/play/p/zdeqTQuDxmS

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
BenchmarkInt-8                      985913821            1.219 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkFloat-8                    616161028            1.990 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkToStringInt-8               6727627           175.8 ns/op        24 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkToStringFloat-8             4459144           269.1 ns/op        24 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkToStringNegativeInt-8       5851466           204.7 ns/op        40 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkToStringNegativeFloat-8     4456899           271.2 ns/op        24 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

int64 version is 40% faster than the one with floats, and ToString for int64 is faster

Sure thing, my CPU is 64-bit with floating point support  in the pipeline, on 32-bit integer-only CPU the results will be different. Still int should outperform the float version.

Comment: thank you for this. I did a bit of testing and using int64 over float64 approximately halves the execution time (my use of math/big was unnecessary as pointed out in the comments above). There is however an issue with the code example you put. It doesn't handle negative latitude and longitude values where the degree is less than 1, e.g. -0.523453332.

Comment: @authoritah my  bad, sorry. Reworked